# The Linked sidebar should show also links to other SE sites

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, linked-questions

The Linked sidebar showing linked-to posts only shows links within the same site. Often, for example on Cross Validated there are links to posts on Math SE or MathOverflow (or other sites) but these are not shown in the Linked sidebar. Why? Such linking would increase the utility of that sidebar.

I am sure the same applies to many other closely related sites.

Comment: @alexolut I'd say it's an exact dupe but I can't vote to close.